# iOS 8 how make navigationBar transparent even rotate

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uinavigationbar

before today, i think it is so easy to make navigationBar transparent.
but i stuck here also 3 hours...

here is my problem,
I want my navigationBar transparent, but navigationItem not.
[image: like this]

but when i rotate my screen, it appear like 
[image: after rotate]

i tried to set my navigationBar background clear;

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar 
    setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navibg"]
    forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsCompact];
```

tried

```
self.navigationController.view.backgroundColor = 
    [UIColor clearColor];
```

tried

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = 
    [UIImage imageNamed:@"navibg"];
```

tried

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] 
    setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navibg"] 
    forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsCompact];
```

And i use xcode 7.2.

Comment: are you added View controller-based status bar appearance in your plist

Comment: >> if ([view isKindOfClass:[NSClassFromString(@"_UINavigationBarBackground") class]]) {
            [view removeFromSuperview];
        }   >>> i did like this, but i think this is not a right way to do it

Answer (score 0):

in your apps plist file add a row call it "View controller-based status bar appearance" and set it make sure it set to Yes and let me know its working or not for customization help pls check http://www.appcoda.com/customize-navigation-status-bar-ios-7/

Comment: hi mate, just solve it. b4 i use 1x1 pixel image. too lazy, now i change it to 320 x 64, it works fine